# Prove that: $a_{1}=0$, $a_{2}=-m$ and $a_{3}=-2 \cdot( \text{number of circles of length 3 in}\, \Omega)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $\Omega=\left(\Omega_{E}, \Omega_{K}\right),\left|\Omega_{E}\right|=n,\left|\Omega_{K}\right|=m$, be a graph with adjacency matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. We write

$$
P(\lambda)=\operatorname{det}\left(\lambda \mathrm{I}_{n}-A\right)=\lambda^{n}+a_{1} \lambda^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n}
$$

for the characteristic polynomial of  $A$. Prove that:

$a_{1}=0$,

$a_{2}=-m$,

$a_{3}=-2 \cdot(  \text{number of circles of length 3 in}\, \Omega)$.

My idea: I need to use the well-known fact from that for the characterstic polynomial

$$
\operatorname{det}\left(\lambda \mathrm{I}_{n}-A\right)=\lambda^{n}+a_{1} \lambda^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n}
$$

of a matrix the following is true

$$
a_{k}=(-1)^{k} \sum_{1 \leq i_{1}<i_{2}<\cdots<i_{k} \leq n} \operatorname{det}\left(A_{i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}}\right)
$$

Also $A_{i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}} \in \mathbb{C}^{k \times k}$ is the principial minor consisting of the rows $i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}$ and the columns $i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}$. But I'm not sure.

Some additional information:

A graph is a pair $G = (V, E)$, where $V$ is a set whose elements are called vertices, and $E$ is a set of paired vertices, whose elements are called edges.

The edges of a graph define a symmetric relation on the vertices, called the adjacency relation. An adjacency matrix is a square matrix used to represent a finite graph. The elements of the matrix indicate whether pairs of vertices are adjacent or not in the graph.  Specifically, two vertices $x$ and $y$ are adjacent if $\{x, y\}$ is an edge. A graph may be fully specified by its adjacency matrix $A$, which is an $n \times n$ square matrix, with $A_{ij}$ specifying the number of connections from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$. For a simple graph, $A_{ij}\in \{0,1\}$, indicating disconnection or connection respectively, meanwhile $A_{ii}=0$.

As I am currently learning for my discrete maths exam, I am again looking at old exam questions. Unfortunately I'm not really sure where to start in this exercise. Thanks in advance!